# C'est mon moment pour/de ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Bonjour,

Faut il dire

> C'est mon moment **POUR** changer le monde

ou

> C'est mon moment **DE** changer le monde

Answer (score 2):

La seconde phrase serait la meilleure, mais  néanmoins elle n'est pas  idiomatique ;  la première ne l'est pas non plus.

On dirait plus couramment ceci.

- C'est le moment pour moi de changer le monde.

Comment: *Pas tout à fait idiomatique* est un *understatement*.

Answer (score 1):

C'est un exemple ou le français ne peut sans doute pas être aussi concis que l'anglais, mais cela oblige aussi a choisir une intention.

On peut mettre l'accent sur l'instant de gloire personnel :

> C'est mon occasion de changer le monde.

> C'est mon heure, celle de changer le monde.

Ou l'aspect temporel / devoir à accomplir :

> C'est l'heure pour moi de changer le monde.

Si on veut souligner l'opportunité fugace :

> C'est l'occasion ou jamais pour moi de changer le monde.

Avec plus de recul, pour contempler la possibilité :

> Voici l'instant ou je peux changer le monde.

Answer (score 0):

Je dirai d'entrée de jeux que `C'est mon moment pour ...` n'est pas le bon choix. On s'implique avec **C'est mon ...** et ensuite on se justifie avec **pour** ce qui sonne mieux que **de** dans ce cas.

Par contre `C'est le moment de ...` est la meilleure formulation. Ici on est détaché, pas impliqué donc aucune justification. L'usage de **pour** est moins approprié que **de**.

Donc `C'est le moment de changer le monde` passe mieux. Mais `C'est mon moment pour changer le monde` reste toute aussi vrai.